# i create a download function for an image but its extension is come as .php

Tags: php, download

hi guys thank in advance for the answer
I created a function where the user can download an image it work fine the image get downloaded but its extension come as .PHP eg(image.php) take a look at the code

just so you know it's only for images and I have tried (Content-Type: image/png) same result
also if I change the extension of the download image back to jpg or png then the image open fine

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){

    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $file="SELECT * FROM jobapplication where id = $id";
    $file_q=mysqli_query($conn,$file);
    $file_run=mysqli_fetch_assoc($file_q);

    $file=$file_run['cvfile'];


    $path= '../cv/' . $file;

    if(file_exists($path)){
        header('content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("content-Disposition: attachment; filename'' ".basename($path))."";
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-length:'.filesize('../cv/' . $file));
        readfile('../cv/' . $file);
        exit();


    }else{

    }
}
```

Comment: Try hard coding the name of a known image file with a correct extension and see if that works.  It will help you isolate the error.

Comment: hi if you mean I should name the  image directly will I cant to that because I a job application form so people submit their cv for the job and I view them so it's not one image

Comment: Do it for a test and so you can see if you can get it with a hard coded file name before making it into a variable.   +1 means thank you.  No +1, no answer next time.

Comment: hi, I tried the hard code but it still comes as.PHP a don't know what the problem in google and youtube it the same method also i don't what whats it mean +1 means thank you. No +1, no answer next time but thankyou

Comment: It means that you click the up arrow next to the person's comment or answer to encourage them to continue helping them.    You hard coded $FN to be something like "FN.PNG" and it came down as "FN.PNG.PHP", right?   My php is very bad but I'm trying to help.  And you looked on the server and the file name was "FN.PNG"?

Comment: hi I don't see an up arrow button  link I have in my question i just give a +1 on one of your question though and the file in the database is FN.png  and when i download it come is a FN.php

Comment: You changed readfile('../cv/' . $file); to readfile('../cv/' . "FN.png"); and it still came down as FN.php?